# Filtering django queryset by slug

Tags: python, django

I would like to filter the Post objects also with the slug, how should one go about this?
The model looks as follows:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    post_json = models.CharField(max_length=100000, blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and the view looks like this.

```
def load_post_json(request):
    obj = Post.objects.filter(author_id=request.user.id)
    data = list(obj.values())
    return JsonResponse({'posts': data})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `url` you can capture the slug:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from app.views import load_post_json

urlpatterns = [
    # …
    path('post/<slug:slug>/', load_post_json, name='post_json'),
    # …
]
```

Then in your view, you can filter in the slug:

```
# app/views.py

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def load_post_json(request, slug):
    obj = Post.objects.filter(author_id=request.user.id, slug=slug)
    data = list(obj.values())
    return JsonResponse({'posts': data})
```

That being said, it might be better to use the [Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to define an API. This has tooling for serializers, etc. and thus makes it more convenient to define sets of views to obtain a list of items, create new ones, etc.

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
>   [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to filter by `slug` too?

If you submit it as a query parameter, simply write:

```
def load_post_json(request):
slug_name= request.data.get('slug_name')
obj = Post.objects.filter(author_id=request.user.id, slug=slug_name)
data = list(obj.values())
return JsonResponse({'posts': data})
```

If you want to extract it from the URL,capture it on `urlpatterns` in `urls.py` file:

```
   urlpatterns = [
    # …
    path('post/<slug_name:slug_name>/', load_post_json),
    # …
    ]
```

then, get it as a function parameter in your `load_post_json` function:

```
   def load_post_json(request, slug_name):
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another alternative way,

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from app.views import load_post_json

urlpatterns = [
    # …
    path('post/', load_post_json, name='post_json'),
    # …
]
```

and the views.py

```
# app/views.py

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def load_post_json(request):
    slug = request.GET.get('slug', None)
    obj = Post.objects.filter(author_id=request.user.id, slug=slug)
    data = list(obj.values())
    return JsonResponse({'posts': data})
```

and the url endpoint,

```
/post/?slug=<your slug here>
```